# Hardware accelerated ffmpeg using MediaCodec on Android?

Tags: ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration

I've tried running for example `ffmpeg -i 1_5111632628432240784.MP4 -c:v h264_mediacodec -c:a aac -b:v 1M -g 60 test.mp4` in Termux in different variations, which yields an output like this, regardless of whether I specify output bitrate or not:

```
amediacodec_ndk @ 0xb400006fa0cc6980 Encoder configure failed, -10000
[h264_mediacodec @ 0xb400006fa0cd2000] MediaCodec configure failed, Generic error in an external library
[vost#0:0/h264_mediacodec @ 0xb400006fa0cb9300] Error initializing output stream: Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

I saw that ffmpeg supports MediaCodec since February 2023: "MediaCodec decoder via NDKMediaCodec, MediaCodec encoder".

The version I have installed is compiled to support it:

```
ffmpeg version 6.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Android (9352603, based on r450784d1) clang version 14.0.7 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 4c603efb0cca074e9238af8b4106c30add4418f6)
  configuration: --arch=aarch64 --as=aarch64-linux-android-clang --cc=aarch64-linux-android-clang --cxx=aarch64-linux-android-clang++ --nm=llvm-nm --pkg-config=/home/builder/.termux-build/_cache/android-r25c-api-24-v2/bin/pkg-config --strip=llvm-strip --cross-prefix=aarch64-linux-android- --disable-indevs --disable-outdevs --enable-indev=lavfi --disable-static --disable-symver --enable-cross-compile --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-jni --enable-lcms2 --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-mediacodec --enable-opencl --enable-shared --prefix=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr --target-os=android --extra-libs=-landroid-glob --disable-vulkan --enable-neon --disable-libfdk-aac
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
```

So my question is, how can I use hardware accelerated video decoding and encoding using ffmpeg on Android in a terminal?

Comment: AFAIK, mediacodec only works if ffmpeg is called from some JVM context. I have no idea why one of the devs even enabled the support in the first place, but at least  I don't think it's possible to make use of it when you run ffmpeg in a shell. Maybe you can ask [here](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/discussions) and tag [the dev who enabled it](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/commit/097206d50d34ab7fc0eb4c0ff20ae80ee73fd901) to see if he can give you any info.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'll do that.