# Re-encoding with ffmpeg fails on Android

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the following command that fails when running on an Android device. I don't think it's related to the overlaying part but to the re-encoding of the video. This same command works perfectly on iOS.

```
ffmpeg -y -i "video-file.mp4" -framerate 60.0 -i "%05d.png" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay" "output-video-file.mp4"
```

The error that I am getting is the following.

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video-file.mp4':
Metadata:
  compatible_brands: isommp41mp42
  major_brand     : mp42
  minor_version   : 1
  creation_time   : 2024-01-03T20:44:54.729000Z
  encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
Duration: 00:00:25.30, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8586 kb/s
Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: hevc (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, 8509 kb/s, 59.91 fps, 60 tbr, 19200 tbn (default)
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2024-01-03T20:44:54.000000Z
    handler_name    : Core Media Video
    vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 62 kb/s (default)
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2024-01-03T20:44:54.000000Z
    handler_name    : Core Media Audio
    vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #1, image2, from '%05d.png':
Duration: 00:00:01.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1280x720, 5 fps, 5 tbr, 5 tbn
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 (hevc) -> overlay (graph 0)
Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
overlay:default (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (h264_mediacodec)
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264_mediacodec @ 0xb400007a3e6347e0] Use 1 as the default MediaFormat i-frame-interval, please set gop_size properly (>= fps)
[amediacodec @ 0xb400007a1c9427f0] android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xffffffc3
[h264_mediacodec @ 0xb400007a3e6347e0] MediaCodec configure failed, Generic error in an external library
[vost#0:0/h264_mediacodec @ 0xb400007a2c8a4490] Error initializing output stream: Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
[aac @ 0xb400007a3e85b6a0] Qavg: 169.544
[aac @ 0xb400007a3e85b6a0] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
```

Comment: For some reason, the default encoder is `h264_mediacodec`. According to the comment to the [following question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/253750), it looks like `h264_mediacodec` only works if ffmpeg is called from some JVM context. Try selecting other encoder using `-c:v` argument. I don't know which video encoders are enabled by FFmpeg for Android, and I can't see it in your post (you didn't post FFmpeg banner).

Comment: @Rotem Thank you. I've used -vcodec libx265 and it's working now. One follow-up question: Is there a command to get the video encoders available on a particular Android device? I see the -encoders option but I am hoping maybe there is a comamnd that outputs just the video encoders without any other characters so it is easier to parse. And what other popular encoders should I look for to use if x265 is not available?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no option to get a list of encoders in simple format. We may also take a look at the build flags, as `--enable-libx264 --enable-libx265`... The fact that an encoder is in the list doesn't mean that it is going to work (as in the case of `h264_mediacodec`). I don't have experience with FFmpeg on Android, and I don't know the popular encoders that are enabled in Android.